# iOS: Call a C function from an Objective-C++ file

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, objective-c++

So there is a C header file (`someFile.h`) which literally just consists of two lines..

```
#include <stdio.h>
char* aFunctionThatTakesACharStarAndReturnsACharStar(char *jdata);
```

.. for which I have an implementation file (`someFile.c`) with the implementation of that method.

I would like to call this method from an Objective-C++ file (`ShinyObjCPlusPlusFile.mm` - because apparently there is no way to call C functions from pure ObjC classes).

**The problem is** that if I do this in `ShinyObjCPlusPlusFile.mm`...

```
#import "someFile.h"

- (void)doSomethingCoolWithThisString:(NSString *)aString {
    char *awesomeChar = aFunctionThatTakesACharStarAndReturnsACharStar([aString UTF8String]);
    // doing smthng cool
}
```

... XCode throws an error on that line, saying "No matching function for call to "aFunctionThatTakesACharStarAndReturnsACharStar"".

**How do I have to do this?**

*This is my first time dealing with pure C, please excuse my dumbness*

**------**
**EDIT:**

Apparently there is nothing wrong with any of it and as Paul Griffiths pointed out you can actually call C functions from Obj-C files.
Renaming ShinyObjCPlusPlusFile.mm to simply ShinyObjCPlusPlusFile.m fixed the issue, whatever it was.

Comment: You certainly can call C functions from Objective-C classes. Are you including `someFile.c` in your project?

Comment: Woah. I just renamed ShinyObjCPlusPlusFile.mm back to ShinyObjCPlusPlusFile.m and now it compiles! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It should have worked for .mm as well.